# How do Bluetooth Controller apps work? (And what would I use to make one)

Tags: android, input, bluetooth

I'm looking to create a Bluetooth Controller app (probably for android) with some specific features for a game I'm making, but I can't find any information on how these work.

Everything I search only comes up with recommendations for the best apps to use.

**Here's what I need to know:**

- How do these things work?
- What libraries could I use to create one of these

I don't really care what language or framework these are for, I'm willing to learn something new in able to make this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links to help you get started:-

- [The Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Scanning iBeacon and Eddystone Using Android BLE Scanner](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/scanning-ibeacon-and-eddystone-using-android-ble-scanner/)
- [(Video) Building Android Apps to Control BLE Devices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeN88yh7YdY)